# Unable to properly mount file systems using NFS version 4 from Solaris 10 to Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, solaris, nfs

I use Ubuntu 16.04 client machine and  Solaris 10 server machine.

When I mount users using nfs4 from `/etc/fstab` file in client machine, I get the owner as nobody.If I use nfs3 then I get the owner as the user who has logged in.

I wonder why the permissions are not getting mounted properly for nfs4.

Please let me know if I am missing something in using nfs4.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can we see your fstab?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the same NFSv4 domain name?

This will show the domain name on Solaris:
`cat /var/run/nfs4_domain`

Not sure where it's set on Ubuntu.

It's usually defined via/in/with DNS.